# Show that if $A=\{1, 2,...\}$, then $S_A$ is an infinite group

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, symmetric-groups, infinite-groups

I want to show that if $A=\{1, 2,...\}$, then $S_A$ is an infinite group.

My proposed solution:

We consider the element $x=(1, 2,..., i, i+1,...)$ of $S_A$ , where we have used cyclic notation for representing elements of permutation groups, noting that there exists no positive finite integer $n$, such that $|x|=n$, we conclude that the cyclic subgroup of $S_A$ generated by $x$ is an infinite group, thus we conclude that $S_A$ is an infinite group.

Is my solution reasonable?
(This is not a Homework problem, that I want to get solved unfairly )

Comment: What does $S_A$ stand for?

Comment: If it were a homework problem, I would say that the "solution" is not written well, and that we just could list infinitely many transpositions $(i,i+1)$ for $i=1,2,3,\ldots $. But since it is not homework, it doesn't matter. By the way, $S_A={\rm Sym}(A)={\rm Sym}(\Bbb N)$.

Comment: If $S_A$ is the symmetric group permuting $A$ this works. Alternatively you could consider all the transpositions $(12),(23),(34),...$ which also gives you an  infinite collection of elements.

Comment: José Carlos Santos, $S_A$ is the group of all permutations of the set A.(Sorry for directly taking your name while replying, but I don't know exactly how should I respectfully greet you).

Comment: Dietrich Burde, so should I then consider my solution to be wrong?

Comment: Your "solution" is wrong in this way: $(1,2,\dots,i, i+1,\dots)$ is not a permutation of $A$. [That is, if I have interpreted the notation correctly. If I haven't your solution is wrong because it is incomprehensible.]

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Shaun, sir, For some technical reason , I couldn't do it, else I would have done that.Now I could and have done it.

Comment: You can have infinite cycles, but they have to be infinite at both ends: for example $x = (\ldots,8,6,4,2,1,3,5,7,\ldots)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

Your $x$ is not a bijection from $A$ to $A$. What maps to $1$? Thus $x\notin S_A$.

---

There is infinitely many distinct elements of the form $(i,i+1)$ in $S_A$ for $i\in A$.

Answer (score 5):

You can have an infinite cycle,
but it needs to be infinite in both directions,  as in @Derek Holt's comment.  Otherwise not all  points are "hit".

Alternative argument:

For any $n\in \Bbb N,$ we have $S_n\le S_\Bbb N\implies \lvert S_\Bbb N\rvert \ge n!.$

Comment: How does this rule out *per se*, e.g., $|S_{\Bbb N}|=2n!$ (i.e. finite)?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, @Devo.

Comment: @Devo $\lvert S_\Bbb N\rvert =2 n!$ can only hold for a fixed $n$. In fact, $S_{\Bbb N}$ doesn't depend on an integer $n$ at all. But the estimate holds for all $n$, so that it cannot have a finite value.